# How to vertical align text in the middle in my case

Tags: html, css

I am trying to vertical align my div texts in my case.

I have something like

```
<div id="wrapper" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-2 test">
             <div class="row test-bar">
                <div class="col-xs-9">
                    <span>Title 1</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3" >
                    <button><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">
           other contents...
        </div>
   </div>
</div>

CSS SASS 

#wrapper{
    margin-top:30px;
      .test {
          margin-right:3px;
          min-height:380px;
             .tesr-bar {
                 background-color:#E3E3E3;
                    span {
                        line-height:25px;
                        vertical-align:middle;
                    }
             }
      }
   }
}
```

For some reason, I can't align the text '`Title 1`' as `vertical-align middle`. Can someone help me about this? Thanks!

Comment: what element do u try to algn with? button?

Comment: div element with col-xs-9 class

Comment: lol, i know, but u want col-xs div stay on the same row with the button or what?

Answer (score 0):

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/en68p2tr/)

```css
span {
    margin:auto;
    display:table;
}
#wrapper {
    margin-top:30px;
    .test {
        margin-right:3px;
        min-height:380px;
        .tesr-bar {
            background-color:#E3E3E3;
            span {
                line-height:25px;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-2 test">
            <div class="row test-bar">
                <div class="col-xs-9"> <span>Title 1</span>

                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <button><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-9">other contents...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```